# How to solve mismatched code dependency issues between two or more different ML models/structures/frameworks?

Tags: nlp, pipelines

I'm fairly new to machine learning. Currently I am trying to build a pipeline that uses two established NLP models. One is BERT that is fairly easy to load and quite structured. Another is FLAIR which has certain dependencies. I am trying to use one environment to load all packages from both, but they obviously use different versions of different packages. For example, different versions of numpy and pytorch. I cannot seem to combine them into one platform. I have faced this problem quite often with combining different models/frameworks (like tensorflow and pytorch) etc.

My question: is there any standard way to deal with these kinds of dependency issues? Do I have to have separate environments to load the respective packages? How do developers commonly deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The most common and used approach is to use virtual environment for both the model.

*"A virtual environment is a Python environment such that the Python interpreter, libraries and scripts installed into it are isolated from those installed in other virtual environments, and (by default) any libraries installed in a “system” Python, i.e., one which is installed as part of your operating system."* (Quoted from Python Doc)

The most used virtual environment packages are : *virtualenv* and *conda*.
I would suggest you to use conda as it is easy to create different python environment without having them installed on the machine.

You can find a detailed discussion of both of them here : https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/